# sed changes are lost (while running cat command on txt file)

Tags: linux, sed

I need to insert a command "new file" in a *test.txt* file at line number 4.

Tried `sed`; I can see the changed file output, but when I again do `cat test.txt`, the changes are gone.

```
sed "4i new file" /test.txt
```

How can I save the changes?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

sed '4i new file' test.txt > tmp && mv tmp test.txt

Answer (score 5):

Use in place edit option `sed -i "4i new file" test.txt`

Without the `-i` option `sed` will not make any changes to the file. It will only print the result.

```
-i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]
    edit files in place (makes backup if SUFFIX supplied)
```